# Can't run Moblin/MeeGo on Intel Core 2 Duo processor based laptop

Tags: linux, intel-core2, meego

I wanted to install MeeGo (formerly, Moblin) in my Acer Aspire 4930 laptop, though I know this OS is targeted towards netbooks based on Intel Atom Processor, but I can't even run it on VirtualBox (latest version) and all I see is black screen that never leads to booting the OS, though when I boot, the bootsplash menu but when I select "Boot Moblin" black screen appears and than nothing happens.

Basically I want to try its unique UI, currently I'm using Ubuntu so is it possible to install the UI of MeeGo in it (via its RPMs) ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I fired up Moblin a few months ago on my Acer 5735 (dual core) in Virtualbox on Fedora 14 and it worked fine so it *should* work unless recent builds have radically changed something relevant. Can't say more than that as I got rid of the install once I had finished looking around.

Comment: @Linker3000: I have Moblin 2.1 and MeeGo 1.1 but unfortunately, none of them works, I tried using it in Live USB drive as well.

Comment: I'll double-check when I get home (about 6 hours from now) - I *may* have kept the original downloads.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the virtualbox guests. Have you tried this one: http://virtualboxes.org/images/moblin-2/

Comment: @Linker3000: haven't tried that, and might not be able to as well, as I'm on dial-up so downloading such a hefty file is out of luck :-(, thanks anyway, I'd still prefer to get the standard ISO working in my laptop instead of any customized images.